# Starting a background service when the OS boots

Tags: java, android, background-service

I'm trying to start my background service when the device boots, but nothing is happening. This is my code:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.test"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Autostart.java**

```
package it.test;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class Autostart extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(arg0, AppService.class);
        arg0.startService(intent);
        Log.e("it.Test", "***** SERVER STARTING CALLED *****");

    }
}
```

**AppService.java**

```
package it.test;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AppService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My AppService Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("it.Test", "***** SERVICE STOPPED *****");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My AppService Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("it.Test", "***** SERVICE STARTED *****");
        /*
        MainActivity.calc();
        MainActivity.save();
        */
    }
}
```

When my phone boots I don't see any toast (I don't see either the "My AppService Started" nor the "My AppService Stopped" toast) and nothing gets logged by the application...
Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?? 
Thanks!

**EDIT: Solution to the problem**
After seeing the post [Trying to start a service on boot on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android/) linked in an answer and after many debugging I found the solution to my problem :) Thank to everyone!

**Modification to AndroidManifest.xml**

Added inside `<application>`:

```
<receiver android:name="it.test.Autostart">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service
    android:name="it.test.AppService"
    android:enabled="true" />
```

Added also:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    [...]
    android:installLocation="internalOnly">
```

**Modifications to AppService.java**
To make the service work, I had to override in the AppService class `onStartCommand` instead of `onStart`, so I completely removed the method `onStart` from my class.
New `onStartCommand`:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My AppService Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("it.Test", "***** SERVICE STARTED ***** from onStartCommand");
    MainActivity.calc(this);
    MainActivity.save();
    return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;//todo I'm not sure about what I have to return
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your broadcast receiver is not registered at AndroidManifest.xml

You need to register the broadcast receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".<RECEIVER_NAME>">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

If your app is installed to external storage it won't receive BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast message. To prevent this you can install your application in internal storage. you can do this just adding this line in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
... >
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32938071/1549700

Comment: The tag `<service>` must be added, or the Sevice won't be called. You also must override `Service#onStartCommand` and not `Service#onStart` (witch is deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

You have you register your broadcast receiver and service under the `<application>` tag

```
 <!-- [START service_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name=".it.test.AppService"
        android:enabled="true" />
    <!-- [END service_listener] -->

    <!-- [START broadcast_receiver] -->
    <receiver android:name=".it.test.Autostart">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- [END broadcast_receiver] -->
```

Comment: Adding the `<service>` tag and the `<reciver>` tags helped, but it isn't enought: `Service#onStartCommand` and not `Service#onStart` (witch is deprecated) must be overridden

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the broadcast receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".Autostart">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this in your manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".it.test.Autostart">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Have you register broadcast receiver in manifest file and also also give boot completed permission in your broadcast receiver, if any problem then ask in comment, your code is perfect.